# How to make scrolling text, without inhibiting the functionality of a game?

Tags: python, pygame

Below is a snippet from a game I am currently making for A-Level coursework. I am making an intro cutscene in which I wish to make text be revealed one letter at a time (scroll, pokemon style). However my current solution requires the use of a for loop per line of text. This is fine for visual effect however it prevents the user from being able to interact with the window. I would like to add a skip button but cannot do so sue to this problem. I tried using more if statements but the code became messy, buggy, and a lot less efficient. Is there an easier, more efficient fix?

```
screen.blit(introImage4,(0,16))
if flags["IntroStage3"] == True:
    for i in range(len(introText[0])):
        introTextImage1 = myFont.render(introText[0][i], True, white)
        screen.blit(introTextImage1,(50 + (myFont.size(introText[0][:i])[0]), 50))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(textFPS)
    for i in range(len(introText[1])):
        introTextImage2 = myFont.render(introText[1][i], True, white)
        screen.blit(introTextImage2,(50 + (myFont.size(introText[1][:i])[0]), 100))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(textFPS)
    for i in range(len(introText[2])):
        introTextImage3 = myFont.render(introText[2][i], True, white)
        screen.blit(introTextImage3,(50 + (myFont.size(introText[2][:i])[0]), 150))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(textFPS)
    flags["IntroStage4"] = True
    flags["IntroStage3"] = False

if flags["IntroStage4"] == True:
    introTextImage1 = myFont.render(introText[0], True, white)
    introTextImage2 = myFont.render(introText[1], True, white)
    introTextImage3 = myFont.render(introText[2], True, white)
    screen.blit(introTextImage1,(50, 50))
    screen.blit(introTextImage2,(50, 100))
    screen.blit(introTextImage3,(50, 150))
    flags["IntroStage5"] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that the event handler can't run a new check until your for loop is done.

the solution is to write an animation function for your text. you can do this by adding a variable which contains the text shown on screen, you can then change the value of this variable to another part of the complete text you want to have scroll based on some time dependent value.

this time dependent value can be the time that has passed since the event that triggered the scrolling text.

just to make it a bit more clear here's an example:

say i want the complete text to be "Alice has a big basket of fruit" but i can only fit one word in my scrolling text box and i want to show it for two seconds:

```
text = "Alice has a big basket of fruit"
def animate_text(text,t): #here t is current unix time minus the unix time whenthat the event that triggered the text scrolling
    text_batches=text.split(' ')
    return text_batches[t//2] if t//2 <= len(text_batches) else return False
```

so now we've split the text into batches instead of nesting a loop in your main loop you can blit the batch corresponding to the time that has passed since the animation started

```
while 1!=0:

    # game loopy stuff here

    blit(animate_text(text,time.time()-time_when_animation_started))
```

now that's all a little messy and pseudocodey and it doesn't perfectly handle your particular situation but you should get the idea here